# NodeJS REST API Model and Service structure

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

I'm writing a medium scale application using Express and MariaDB/Cassandra as my back-end.

I'm trying to follow the *Model Service Controller* pattern. My initial design had thin Controllers and fat Models, but I felt that the Models contained a lot of code, and probably needed to be broken down into separate files. So now I have a Service layer that sits in between the controller and the model.

I'm trying to achieve 1-1 mapping between Controller/API methods and Service Methods.

Each single service method will try to contain the code for all the operations to be performed by that API method. My validation logic is in the Service. This Service might then internally call multiple models using the `async` nodejs module, process and pass on the response to other models. But this is proving to become a problem.

Imagine I'm registering a user, where each user belongs to an organization. -

1. I check if the user already exists.
2. If not I create an Organization for the user.
3. I get the organization ID.
4. I create the user, mapping the organization ID in the user's table.

All this is being carried out inside a transaction.

If I put the validation in the Service, then even though I do not have a controller/API for inserting an organization, I will have to have a Service for insertion of organization so that the validation can be performed there. This would break the 1-1 mapping between Service and Controller/API.

Another problem with putting the validation in the Model is that it would be performed immediately before insertion of the organization or user. Now if the organization data is correct, but user data is incorrect, the organization will actually be inserted but then will have to be rolled back.

Is there a better way to handle this? Should I perform the validation for Users and Organization initially in the Service, and then perform it again inside the Model or is there a better way to handle this? I'm open to performing drastic changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clean good way to handle this. I am not familiar with using MariaDB/Cassandra but I went through this using Express/Mongooose/MongoDB. The issue is that sometimes you need to perform validation that is not database related - i.e. a contact form, some other non database action. Other times you need the database native validation for things such as unique field check. In the case of Mongoose there have been attempts to create service based validators to check for uniqueness but they have resulted (per the Mongoose author) in not working 100% of the time perhaps due to race conditions.

The way that I approached this was to create a frontend/route validation service/middleware to check for required parameters etc.. Some of these could be handled in the db but, as in the contact form case, some just need to be in the service. I have extended the Error object in multiple ways (for things like resources not found, front end validation, etc) to handle these error messages.

I then make sure all errors (Frontend service, Mongo, Mongoose) bubble up and are passed in my controllers using `next(err)`. All errors are then funneled into an error middleware that converts the different error models into a unified format that I then output to json. The end result is a lot of flexibility as to where errors are handled while maintaining a very clean setup.

Comment: Exactly the approach I have used, it's about as clean as it'll get, I think.

Comment: So the 1-1 controller to service mapping is a good way to go? I expect it'll be easier for a developer to work with all the code in one place. Of course I have to ensure I follow the DRY principle.

Comment: I have a piece of middleware that uses a switch statement using http verb + path (i.e 'POST /api/auth') for all routes. I use express-validator to validate all params (besides things like unique) and then build a RestError (extended from Error) object using issues that came up. I then next(err) it. In another piece of middleware I run my error handling. In there I have some code that checks if it's a RestError, ValidationError (Mongoose), MongoError (MongoDB native) and so on and create a standardized object that I can dump out to json. I never throw errors, always funnel them with next().